# Inner query doubts

Tags: sql

```
select :name from (select empName from Employee);
```

Suppose the Inner query `(select empName from Employee)` gives one name 'XYZ'.

And as we know the Inner query and sub query execute first then why we not write directly

`select :name from XYZ` inplace of writing `select :name from (select empName from Employee)`;

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense.  A `from` clause lists tables and subqueries.  As you describe the situation, `'XYZ'` is a value not a table.

Answer (score 0):

Because `FROM` expects a table source and 'XYZ' is not a table, it is a string value and makes up an incorrect syntax when used like that. A `SELECT` statement in the inner query will return as a table source.

Answer (score 0):

I belive, when you query for something it returns set of records and XYZ used directly is a string. You cant use FROM to access XYZ, you need a table.

Answer (score 0):

A colon usually marks a variable. So say :name = 'John', then the query

```
select :name from (select empName from Employee);
```

would result in n times 'John' with n = number of records in table Employee.

Same as

```
select :name from Employee;
```

The subquery

```
select empName from Employee
```

does not give one name 'XYZ'. It gives you the names of all employees.

If you want to ask if `select empname from (select empname from employee)` is the same as `select empname from employee`, then yes, it is. In this example it doesn't make much sense to use an inner query (a "derived table" as it is called), but there are more complex queries where derived tables make very much sense.